# understanding @EntityListener behavior during a @Transactional test

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an EntityListener that has a `@PrePersist` & `@PreUpdate` method (which simply logs the call).  I created a test method where I `save(entity)`.  That will fire the listener method.  However, when I annotate the test method with `@Transactional` (so that the changes to `entity` are rolled back after the test), my listener method does not fire.  I also tried `saveAndFlush(entity)`, but that did not work either.  I expected the console log to be written to as soon as the entity was saved.  Is that a correct assumption or am I not understanding how transactions are implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Like any listener, you will need to register the event to be triggered using the bukkit event system. Here's an example from a [bukkit](https://bukkit.org/threads/entity-listener-problem.52389/#post-884073) thread

```
PluginManager pm = pl.getServer().getPluginManager();
pm.registerEvent(Event.Type.FOOD_LEVEL_CHANGE, new EntityListener(){
    public void onFoodLevelChange(FoodLevelChangeEvent event){
            // code
        }
}, Event.Priority.Normal, this);
```

Comment: Um, maybe you were answering a different question?  I don't think this is related to [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa)